# JavaFX printing rows into TextFields

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, tableview

I have a table with on my SQL server with 16 rows, I am trying to print out the `BasePT` column into a bunch of TextFields but I cannot figure out how. Am I suppose to create a separate string for each row? How can I minimize code and be able to get each row to show up on each TextField?

//Table 100

[image: Table 100]

// Button

```
public void loadButton(){
    connection = SqlConnection.FormulaConnection();
    try {
        String SQL = "Select * FROM '100';";
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
        while (rs.next()) {

//insert BasePT from Row Yellow into YellowText TextField
            String Yellow = rs.getString("BasePt");
            YellowText.setText(Yellow);

//insert BasePT from Row 012 Yellow into TwoYellowText TextField
            String TwoYellow = rs.getString("BasePT");
            TwoYellowText.setText(TwoYellow);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you not use TableView?

Comment: Do you need `TextField`s? Looks like `Text`s would be sufficient. Is the printing API relevant here or does "print" in this case mean "show"? Also could you elaborate more on the desired result? Also "making each row show up on each `TextField`" doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following examples I use a array of `String[]` arrays with elements for the row data. It should be easy enough to use the data from the database instead.

## The standard way: TableView

Simply use a `Item` class containing a property for each table column:

```
public class Item {

    public Item(String baseFormula, String basePt) {
        this.baseFormula = new SimpleStringProperty(baseFormula);
        this.basePt = new SimpleStringProperty(basePt);
    }

    private final StringProperty basePt;
    private final StringProperty baseFormula;

    public final String getBaseFormula() {
        return this.baseFormula.get();
    }

    public final void setBaseFormula(String value) {
        this.baseFormula.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty baseFormulaProperty() {
        return this.baseFormula;
    }

    public final String getBasePt() {
        return this.basePt.get();
    }

    public final void setBasePt(String value) {
        this.basePt.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty basePtProperty() {
        return this.basePt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" + "basePt=" + basePt.get() + ", baseFormula=" + baseFormula.get() + '}';
    }

}
```

And use a `TableView` with a column for each database column. Use a `cellFactory` that displays `TextField`s and modifies the property belonging to the column on a change of the `TextField`'s text property:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

    Callback<TableColumn<Item, String>, TableCell<Item, String>> factory = column -> new TableCell<Item, String>() {
        private final TextField textField;

        {
            textField = new TextField();
            textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // write to property 
                WritableValue<String> property = (WritableValue<String>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                property.setValue(newValue);
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(textField);
                if (!Objects.equals(textField.getText(), item)) {
                    // only modify if TextField wasn't source of the change
                    // to prevent carret movement
                    textField.setText(item);
                }
            }
        }

    };

    TableColumn<Item, String> formulaColumn = new TableColumn<>("baseFormula");
    formulaColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().baseFormulaProperty());
    formulaColumn.setCellFactory(factory);

    TableColumn<Item, String> ptColumn = new TableColumn<>("basePt");
    ptColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().basePtProperty());
    ptColumn.setCellFactory(factory);

    table.getColumns().addAll(formulaColumn, ptColumn);

    String[][] data = {
        {"Hello", "World"},
        {"Hello2", "World2"},
        {"Hello3", "World3"},
        {"Hello4", "World4"},
        {"Hello5", "World5"},
        {"Hello6", "World6"}
    };

    for (String[] d : data) {
        table.getItems().add(new Item(d[0], d[1]));
    }

    Button btn = new Button("print");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println(table.getItems()));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(table, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

## Alternative

If you don't want to use a `TableView`, `GridPane` would be a suitable `Pane` to produce a layout like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    String[][] data = {
        {"Hello", "World"},
        {"Hello2", "World2"},
        {"Hello3", "World3"},
        {"Hello4", "World4"},
        {"Hello5", "World5"},
        {"Hello6", "World6"}
    };

    Insets margin = new Insets(4);

    int nextRow = 1;
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    Text heading1 = new Text("BaseFormula");
    Text heading2 = new Text("BasePT");

    GridPane.setMargin(heading1, margin);
    GridPane.setMargin(heading2, margin);

    gridPane.addRow(0, heading1, heading2);
    for (String[] d : data) {
        TextField tf = new TextField(d[0]);
        TextField tf2 = new TextField(d[1]);

        GridPane.setMargin(tf, margin);
        GridPane.setMargin(tf2, margin);

        gridPane.addRow(nextRow++, tf, tf2);
    }

    // add lines

    // subtract stroke width
    DoubleBinding height = gridPane.heightProperty().subtract(1);
    // margin = 1/2 stroke width
    Insets vMargin = new Insets(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0);

    // add vertical lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Line vLine = new Line();
        GridPane.setMargin(vLine, vMargin);
        System.out.println(vLine.getStrokeWidth());
        vLine.endYProperty().bind(height);
        gridPane.add(vLine, i, 0, 1, nextRow);
    }

    // procede accordingly with horizontal lines
    DoubleBinding width = gridPane.widthProperty().subtract(1);
    Insets hMargin = new Insets(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5);

    for (int i = 0; i <= nextRow; i++) {
        Line hLine = new Line();
        GridPane.setMargin(hLine, hMargin);
        hLine.setStartX(1);
        hLine.endXProperty().bind(width);

        // Insert at the top of the cell
        GridPane.setValignment(hLine, VPos.TOP);
        gridPane.add(hLine, 0, i, 2, 1);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new Group(gridPane)), 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do NOT want to use a Tableview as yelliver suggested, you can try this:

```
public VBox loadButton(){
    connection = SqlConnection.FormulaConnection();
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    try {
        String SQL = "Select * FROM '100';";
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String yellow = rs.getString("BasePt");
            TextField textField = new TextField(yellow);
            vBox.getChildren().add(textField);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vBox;
}
```

You can then add the VBox where you want to have all the textFields.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace this snippet with your `ResultSet rs`

```
 ResultSet rs = null;//reference it to your rs
        TableView<String[]> tv = new TableView<String[]>();
        final int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for(int i =1; i <= columnCount; i++){
            TableColumn<String[], String> tc = new TableColumn<String[], String>();
            tc.setText(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            final int k = i-1;
            tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<
                    String[],String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<String[],
                        String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[k]);
                }
            });
            tc.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<String[],String>,
                    TableCell<String[],String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<String[], String> call(TableColumn<String[],
                        String> param) {
                    return new TableCell<String[], String>(){
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(String arg0, boolean arg1) {
                            super.updateItem(arg0, arg1);
                            if(arg1){
                                setText("");
                                return;
                            }else{
                                setText(arg0);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }
        while(rs.next()){
            String[] s = new String[columnCount];
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++){
                s[i -1] = rs.getString(i);
            }
            tv.getItems().add(s);
        }
```

This will put you in the right direction. Hope it helps/.